# Load event called way too often

Tags: jquery

I want to reload an image once it has been loaded. Here is my code:

```
$(function () {
    function reload() {
        console.log('Inside reload');
        var srcImage = 'http://cam2.camvine.com/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=320x240' + '&d=' + (new Date()).getTime();

        $('img')
            .attr('src', srcImage)
            .load(function () {
                setTimeout(reload, 500);
            })
            .error(function () {
                setTimeout(reload, 1000);
            });
    }

    reload();
});
```

For some reason, the `load` event gets called tens of times per second, eventually freezing my browser. [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/kdHD4/1/) is a fiddle. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With every `reload` you are adding a new load-event-handler to the already existing one.

```
$(function () {
    function reload(first_run) {
        console.log('Inside reload');
        var srcImage = 'http://cam2.camvine.com/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=320x240&d=' + (+new Date()),
            img = $('img');

        if (first_run === true) {
            img.load(function() {
                setTimeout(reload, 500);
            });   
        }
        img.attr('src', srcImage);
    }

    reload(true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're adding *another* "load" handler to the element on every iteration. Each "load" event, therefore, will result in *all* the handlers being invoked.  They'll add *more* handlers, and after a short while there'll be a whole lot of them.

You could unbind the handler or else just leave it and check for its existence somehow:

```
function reload() {
    console.log('Inside reload');
    var srcImage = 'http://cam2.camvine.com/axis-cgi/jpg/image.cgi?resolution=320x240' + '&d=' + (new Date()).getTime();

    var $img = $('img');
    $img
        .attr('src', srcImage);

    if (!$img.hasClass('load-ready'))
      $img
        .addClass('load-ready')
        .load(function () {
            setTimeout(reload, 500);
        })
        .error(function () {
            setTimeout(reload, 1000);
        });
}
```

[Here is your jsfiddle, updated.](http://jsfiddle.net/Pointy/T4WEu/)